# How to get the user that execute an asynchronous method?

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous, spring-security

I have an application that runs many asynchronous process that can take ten or twenty minutes.

On error, I use a AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler that only writes a log error. I need to notify the user that something wrong happened.

Now I am using a "DelegatingSecurityContextAsyncTaskExecutor" which shares the spring security user between threads. But when I logout, it is deleted and the user in the context null.

This not work fine for me, I want the user who ran the method, not the current in the context,I need him to send a message to your personal mailbox.

How I can get the user that execute the method?

My code:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class SpringAsyncConfig implements AsyncConfigurer {

    @Override
    @Bean(name = "asyncExecutor")
    public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {

        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(1);
        executor.setThreadGroupName("MyCustomExecutor");
        executor.setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(true);
        executor.setBeanName("asyncExecutor");
        executor.initialize();

        DelegatingSecurityContextAsyncTaskExecutor securityExecutor = new DelegatingSecurityContextAsyncTaskExecutor(executor);

        return securityExecutor;
    }

    @Override
    public AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler getAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler() {
        return new CustomAsyncExceptionHandler();
    }

}

public class CustomAsyncExceptionHandler implements AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler {

    private static final Logger LOG = LogManager.getLogger(CustomAsyncExceptionHandler.class);

    @Override
    public void handleUncaughtException(Throwable ex, Method method, Object... params) {
        LOG.error(
                String.format("Error in async method %s with params: %s: Excepcion: %s",
                        method.getName(), params.toString(), ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(ex)), ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am guessing your logout tell's spring security to invalidate the user login.